# Descending within group without changing the order

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to the sort column `C` in descending order within the group without changing the existing order of the group. How can i achieve it!

```
ab <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a3'),
                 B = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 C = c(2,3,5,6,8,9))
```

Dataframe:

```
   A B C
1 a1 1 2
2 a1 2 3
3 a2 3 5
4 a2 4 6
5 a3 5 8
6 a3 6 9
```

Code I tried but changes the order and does sorting:

```
ab %>% arrange(A,B,desc(C))
```

Expected Result: Here it will only sort the numbers but the group A, B remains same as dataframe.

```
   A B C
1 a1 1 3
2 a1 2 2
3 a2 3 6
4 a2 4 5
5 a3 5 9
6 a3 6 8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

ab %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(C = sort(C, decreasing = TRUE))  

#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   A [3]
#>   A         B     C
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a1        1     3
#> 2 a1        2     2
#> 3 a2        3     6
#> 4 a2        4     5
#> 5 a3        5     9
#> 6 a3        6     8
```

#### Update:

Addressing OP's follow-up question about grouping by column `B` for other purposes:

```r
# a new dataset to have two rows with the same A and B value
ab <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a3'),
                 B = c(1,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 C = c(2,4,3,5,6,8,9)) 

library(dplyr)

ab %>% 
  group_by(A,B) %>% 
  mutate(S = sum(C)) %>% 
  group_by(A) %>% 
  mutate(C = sort(C, decreasing = TRUE))  
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   A [3]
#>   A         B     C     S
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a1        1     4     6
#> 2 a1        1     3     6
#> 3 a1        2     2     3
#> 4 a2        3     6     5
#> 5 a2        4     5     6
#> 6 a3        5     9     8
#> 7 a3        6     8     9
```

Comment: Since in my original data i am also grouping by both A and B, can u add grouping by B too

Comment: @prog no, it won't work. You can group by `B` too (`group_by(A,B)`) do your other calculation, then `ungroup` and `group(A)` and do the sorting.

Comment: Could you also please add that code to your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You are not sorting the data, you are actually changing `C` to something new since you are breaking up existing rows. You therefore need to `mutate` like so. Note that I am inferring that you want to sort `C` within each group of `A` since that matches your expected output, though this was not spelled out in the question.

```r
library(dplyr)
ab <- data.frame(A = c('a1','a1','a2','a2','a3','a3'),
                 B = c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                 C = c(2,3,5,6,8,9)) 
ab %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(C2 = sort(C, decreasing = TRUE))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   A [3]
#>   A         B     C    C2
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a1        1     2     3
#> 2 a1        2     3     2
#> 3 a2        3     5     6
#> 4 a2        4     6     5
#> 5 a3        5     8     9
#> 6 a3        6     9     8
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I am trying to group by both A and B, ```ab %>%
  group_by(A,B) %>%
  mutate(C2 = sort(C, decreasing = TRUE))``` but it does not gets in desc order

Comment: @prog because when you group with `A` and `B` (at least for the example dataset here) you would end up with each row to be in a separate group (each row has different combination of `A` and `B` as follows: `a1 & 1`, `a1 & 2`, `a2 & 3`, ...); therefore, when you are sorting, you are sorting one row only. you want to sort column `C` but keep `A` and `B` in the same order. What we have, does that for you.